# Bootstrap grid in container is not 100% width - but a DIV set to 100% width shows correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I have a bootstrap grid within a container. This grid is not showing at 100% width. But a plain div set to 100% width in the same container, does show full width.

The grid seems to have a right margin for some reason.

Any takers?

Here's a screenshot of what is going on. Code below.

[image: Here's a screenshot of what is going on. Code below.]

```html
<div class="container">

  <div style="width:100%; background-color:pink;">100% width</div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6" style="background-color:red;">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="col-6" style="background-color:blue;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12" style="background-color: lime;">2</div>
        <div class="col-6" style="background-color: orange;">3</div>
        <div class="col-6" style="background-color: grey;">4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div style="width:100%; background-color:pink;">100% width</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6" style="background-color:red;">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="col-6" style="background-color:blue;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12" style="background-color: lime;">2</div>
        <div class="col-6" style="background-color: orange;">3</div>
        <div class="col-6" style="background-color: grey;">4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div  style="width:100%; background-color:pink;">100% width</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6" style="background-color:red;">
         1
      </div>
      <div class="col-6" style="background-color:blue;">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12" style="background-color: lime;">2</div>
            <div class="col-6" style="background-color: orange;">3</div>
            <div class="col-6" style="background-color: grey;">4</div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```